# Remove mat button focus from mat menu

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

How can I remove the black outline from my `mat-menu-item`?
[Like this one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4jar.png)

```
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu4" style="margin-left:10px;" [disableRipple]="true">
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>

<mat-menu #menu4="matMenu">
<button id="deactvateBtn" [disableRipple]="true" mat-menu-item>
  <i [class]="!row['isActive'] ? 'fas fa-user-check' : 'fas fa-user-slash'"></i>
  <span>{{ (!row['isActive'] ? 'Activate' : 'Deactivate') | titlecase }}</span>
</button>
</mat-menu>
```

I tried overriding the `.mat-button-focus-overlay` class with this:

```
.mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color: whitesmoke!important;
}
```

But the outline is still there.

Other options I tried:

```
.mat-button-focus-overlay .cdk-program-focused {
    background-color: transparent!important;
}

.mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-item ng-tns-c98-13 {
    background-color: yellow!important;
}
```

Comment: please add your html code here where you are creating mat item

Comment: @AliasgherNooruddin edited my post :)

Answer (score 1):

This is very very late but I think I found a solution that works for Angular 15 with all Angular Material components.

```
//In src/styles.scss
body { 
    --mat-focus-indicator-border-width: 0;
    --mat-mdc-focus-indicator-border-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: This did the trick and I like this solution more than the rest. Also had to set `--mat-focus-indicator-display: block;` because the display none was hiding my own `::before` pseudo element.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`::ng-deep`](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) to re-style the mat buttons.

```
::ng-deep .mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color: whitesmoke!important;
}
```

Comment: are you sure changing `mat-button-focus-overlay` ? can you inspect element browser, and try to find the necessary class as you want?

Comment: but just make sure ::ng-deep is necessary

Answer (score 0):

Use `::ng-deep` to re-style the mat buttons.

```
::ng-deep .mat-button-focus-overlay {
    border: none !important;
 }
```

use this css, what you are trying to hide is not background but border color so you need to disable the border.

or try this css

```
::ng-deep .mat-button {
    border: none !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but in case someone else runs into this in the future, the class that I had to override was button:focus for .mat-menu-item and it was not the border but the outline that I had to get rid off, I added this to my css and it worked:

```
button.mat-menu-item:focus{
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is even later - but what worked for me today was

```
.mat-focus-indicator::before {
  border: none;    
}
```

in your global styles.css.

In chrome you can inspect the button and play around with the CSS. That's how I found it.